# Some kind of rotation Map from the cirlce to circle

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Suppose $p,q,a,b$ are integers such that $ap+bq=1$

Let $f : S^1 \times S^1 \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1$ $\\$

$f(z,w) = (z^p w^b, z^q w^a)$  $\\$

then what is this map?
I was asked this question while studying algebraic topology. So I think I don't have to know exactly what this map is, I will have to know how it works on homology groups.